# Shell script assigns Access Control List to file

Tags: shell, acl

How can I use a shell script to create a file w/o ACL ... I just want chmod 644 {filename} ? This script takes a pgn file and separates the individual game scores (pgn chess notation) and writes the games to individual files based on an incremented supplied value.. 6444.pgn 6445.pgn ... 6446.pgn etc. This script WAS working just prior to my updrade from Linux Mint 17 to LM 18. But not any more.

```
#!/bin/bash
# INSTRUCTIONS:
# EDit IGS-YYYY-MM-DD clean up English.
# type: prepare_bulk IGS-YYYY-MM-DD {last game} 3rd parameter = annotator's initials 
# (Fixes errors in Igor's game submissions and writes the individual gamescores from larger pgn file )
# (And convert xx00 to XXXX.pgn)

AUTHOR='{(Randy MacKenzie)}' #$3   

OBJECT=IGS-$1.pgn; ULFILE="/home/rmack/Downloads/$OBJECT"; TARGET=/mnt/www/cccr/games/$OBJECT;

offset=$2; dos2unix -q $ULFILE; awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/{\n/, "{")} 1' $ULFILE >junk.txt;

(A lot of awk and sed goes here)

cp junk.txt $TARGET; 

chmod 644 $TARGET;  

cd /home/rmack/www/cccr/games/; csplit -s $TARGET /Event\ / {*}; rm /home/rmack/www/cccr/games/xx00;

for file in xx[0-9]*; do
num0=${file##*x}; num=${num0#0};  (( newnum = num + offset ))
mv $file ${newnum}.pgn;  branch=${newnum}.pgn; 
echo $newnum; chmod 777 $branch; cat "$AUTHOR" >> "$branch"; 
echo "$AUTHOR" >> "$branch"; 

chmod 644 $branch;

done





chmod: changing permissions of '.pgn': Permission denied
rmack@porter ~ $ ls -lah /mnt/www/cccr/games/IGS-2016-09-14.pgn 
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 rmack rmack 3.0K Sep 18 15:40 /mnt/www/cccr/games/IGS-    2016-09-14.pgn
rmack@porter ~ $ 

via man page 'ls'

"If the file or directory has extended security information, the  permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a '+' character."

This generally means the file is encumbered with access restrictions outside of the traditional Unix permissions - likely Access Control List (ACL).
```

Comment: `chmod 777` is a **horrible** idea. It means that even processes that aren't supposed to have meaningful access to anything at all (ie. sandboxed authentication code running as `nobody`) can *write to and execute* content. Just say no.

Comment: ...as for how to set an ACL, check the man page to `setfacl` (or `getfacl` to read it). That said, that isn't actually an on-topic StackOverflow question, as it's in no way specific to programming -- try SuperUser or Unix SE.

Comment: ...even if this is something like a scoreboard for a game, you're making the software that parses that scoreboard into exposed attack surface. If you have something like a `games` group, being able to set group read+write permissions for real human users who play games are exactly what it exists for.

Comment: It looks as if that file is *already* 777 (albeit with some other restrictions). If you want to `create a file w/o ACL`, why not copy it? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Since it is on `/mnt` file system, maybe the file system is mounted readonly (though I think the error would be EROFS for that, not EPERM).  If the file is not an executable, it should not have execute permission.  If it is executable, it should not have public write permission.  So the 777 permissions are wrong, one way or another.

Comment: OK I will use 644 instead of 777 file permission.